# How to create a custom Login/ sign up form with custom role in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I am totally new to **Magento** and want to know how to create a custom  `Login/ signup form` with custom defined role in **Magento 2.1**.
please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

Goto :

```
 vendor->magento->module-customer->view->frontend->layout
copy customer_account_create.xml
```

In your module

```
[namepace]->[modulename]->view->frontend->layout->customer_account_create.xml
```

**Step 2:**
change your block and template file you want to display

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="[**your Block path**]" name="customer_form_register" template="[**Your phtml file path**]">
        <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
        <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**step 3:**
Fire PHP upgrade command

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate more..
i want a custom registration form, and login form in my module.

Comment: can u tell me at which point u dont understand

Comment: i want to build up a multivendor store in magento 2 and want to start with custom vendor registration and login page but please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I override registration page of magento in my custom module.
for that:

1. Create custom module
2. Create customer_acount_index
       xml file in [namespace]->[modulename]->view->frontend->layout

code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_create_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="[yournamespacename]\[yourmodulename]\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Create register.phtml file inside view->templates->form->register.phtml.
4. Run upgrade Command.

This form will be called when customer click on create an account.

Comment: thanks mam,
i will do it step by step but please keep in touch

Comment: mam, can u please create a block for adding a vendor..
also please suggest what should be the database schema.. i mean should i create a separate table for vendor details or extend the default customer table in database and how

Comment: Invalid block type: Learning\HelloPage\Block\Form\Register

Comment: You don't need to create a custom table just add action action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPostActionUrl() ?>"

Comment: hi i created a block with this

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot declare class Register, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Learning/HelloPage/Block/Form/Register.php on line 6

Comment: the above error i got

Comment: if i delete theblock

Comment: got this 
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Learning\HelloPage\Block\Form\Register
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Learning\HelloPage\Block\Form\Register does not exist

Comment: check namespace you specified

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your custom data with customer information then create a controller Learning\HelloPage\Controller\Index\CreatePost.php copy below code in that file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Learning\Hellopage\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
{
    /** @var AccountManagementInterface */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /** @var Address */
    protected $addressHelper;

    /** @var FormFactory */
    protected $formFactory;

    /** @var SubscriberFactory */
    protected $subscriberFactory;

    /** @var RegionInterfaceFactory */
    protected $regionDataFactory;

    /** @var AddressInterfaceFactory */
    protected $addressDataFactory;

    /** @var Registration */
    protected $registration;

    /** @var CustomerInterfaceFactory */
    protected $customerDataFactory;

    /** @var CustomerUrl */
    protected $customerUrl;

    /** @var Escaper */
    protected $escaper;

    /** @var CustomerExtractor */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
    protected $urlModel;

    /** @var DataObjectHelper  */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    private $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $customerSession
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
     * @param Address $addressHelper
     * @param UrlFactory $urlFactory
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
     * @param RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory
     * @param AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
     * @param CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory
     * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
     * @param Registration $registration
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param AccountRedirect $accountRedirect
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
        Address $addressHelper,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
        AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
        CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
        Registration $registration,
        Escaper $escaper,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
         \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
    ) {

        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
        $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->regionDataFactory = $regionDataFactory;
        $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->customerDataFactory = $customerDataFactory;
        $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->registration = $registration;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
        $this->date = $date;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add address to customer during create account
     *
     * @return AddressInterface|null
     */
    protected function extractAddress()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
            return null;
        }

        $addressForm = $this->formFactory->create('customer_address', 'customer_register_address');
        $allowedAttributes = $addressForm->getAllowedAttributes();

        $addressData = [];

        $regionDataObject = $this->regionDataFactory->create();
        foreach ($allowedAttributes as $attribute) {
            $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $value = $this->getRequest()->getParam($attributeCode);
            if ($value === null) {
                continue;
            }
            switch ($attributeCode) {
                case 'region_id':
                    $regionDataObject->setRegionId($value);
                    break;
                case 'region':
                    $regionDataObject->setRegion($value);
                    break;
                default:
                    $addressData[$attributeCode] = $value;
            }
        }
        $addressDataObject = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $addressDataObject,
            $addressData,
            '\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface'
        );
        $addressDataObject->setRegion($regionDataObject);

        $addressDataObject->setIsDefaultBilling(
            $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false)
        )->setIsDefaultShipping(
            $this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false)
        );
        return $addressDataObject;
    }

    /**
     * Create customer account action
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {


        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/create/', ['_secure' => true]);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        $this->session->regenerateId();

        try {

            $address = $this->extractAddress();
            $addresses = $address === null ? [] : [$address];

            $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
            $customer->setAddresses($addresses);

            $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
            $confirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation');
            $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeAuthUrl();

            $this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);

            $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);


            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
                $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
            }

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'customer_register_success',
                ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
            );

            $confirmationStatus = $this->accountManagement->getConfirmationStatus($customer->getId());
            if ($confirmationStatus === AccountManagementInterface::ACCOUNT_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED) {
                $email = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail());
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __(
                        'You must confirm your account. Please check your email for the confirmation link or <a href="%1">click here</a> for a new link.',
                        $email
                    )
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
                $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/index', ['_secure' => true]);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($url));
            } else {
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess($this->getSuccessMessage());
                $requestedRedirect = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                if (!$this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $requestedRedirect) {
                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($requestedRedirect));
                    $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
                $resultRedirect = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
            }
            if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                $metadata->setPath('/');
                $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
            }

            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (StateException $e) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $message = __(
                'There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%1">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.',
                $url
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($error->getMessage()));
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($this->escaper->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
        }

        $this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/create/', ['_secure' => true]);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    /**
     * Make sure that password and password confirmation matched
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @param string $confirmation
     * @return void
     * @throws InputException
     */
    protected function checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation)
    {
        if ($password != $confirmation) {
            throw new InputException(__('Please make sure your passwords match.'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve success message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSuccessMessage()
    {
        if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
            if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your shipping address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            } else {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your billing address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            }
        } else {
            $message = __('Thank you for registering with %1.', $this->storeManager->getStore()->getFrontendName());
        }
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Then set form action in register.phtml
as : action="getPostActionUrl() ?>"

Comment: but how do i add addtional field in my phtml file